# VB.NET. Indexator and Property conflict

Tags: vb.net

I need to have an indexator and property with the same names

```
Public Class WsItemGrpType
    Private _redefined As WsItemIcType
    Public Sub New(ByVal redefined As WsItemIcType)
        _redefined = redefined
        WsItemIcChar = New WsItemIcCharType(_redefined)
    End Sub
    Public WsItemIcChar As WsItemIcCharType
    Public Class WsItemIcCharType
        Private _redefined As WsItemIcType
        Private _current As Integer = 0
        Private _length As Integer = 9
        Public ReadOnly Property Length() As Integer
            Get
                Return _length
            End Get
        End Property
        Public Sub New(ByVal redefined As WsItemIcType)
            _redefined = redefined
        End Sub

        Default Public Property WsItemIcChar(i As Integer) As Char
            Get
                _current = i
                Return Char.Parse(_redefined.WsItemIc.Substring(_current * 1, 1))
            End Get
            Set(value As Char)
                _redefined.WsItemIc = _redefined.WsItemIc.Remove(_current * 1, 1).Insert(_current * 1, value.ToString())
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property WsItemIcChar() As Char
            Get
                Return Char.Parse(_redefined.WsItemIc.Substring(_current * 1, 1))
            End Get
            Set(value As Char)
                _redefined.WsItemIc = _redefined.WsItemIc.Remove(_current * 1, 1).Insert(_current * 1, value.ToString())
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Class
```

Error: Error    8   'Public Default Property WsItemIcChar(i As Integer) As Char' and 'Public Property WsItemIcChar As Char' cannot overload each other because only one is declared 'Default'.

How can I use both Property and Indexator without changing their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "indexator," but you can overload your property in two ways:

1. Declare the second as Default,

   ```
   Default Public Property WsItemIcChar(i As Integer) As Char
       Get
           _current = i
           Return Char.Parse(_redefined.WsItemIc.Substring(_current * 1, 1))
       End Get
       Set(value As Char)
           _redefined.WsItemIc = _redefined.WsItemIc.Remove(_current * 1, 1).Insert(_current * 1, value.ToString())
       End Set
   End Property

   Default Public Property WsItemIcChar() As Char
       Get
           Return Char.Parse(_redefined.WsItemIc.Substring(_current * 1, 1))
       End Get
       Set(value As Char)
           _redefined.WsItemIc = _redefined.WsItemIc.Remove(_current * 1, 1).Insert(_current * 1, value.ToString())
       End Set
   End Property
   ```
2. Declare `i` as Optional,

   ```
   Default Public Property WsItemIcChar(Optional i As Integer = 0) As Char
       Get
           If (i <> 0) Then _current = i
           Return Char.Parse(_redefined.WsItemIc.Substring(_current * 1, 1))
       End Get
       Set(value As Char)
           _redefined.WsItemIc = _redefined.WsItemIc.Remove(_current * 1, 1).Insert(_current * 1, value.ToString())
       End Set
   End Property
   ```

Comment: I must do like this as the result: WsItemGrp.WsItemIcChar(WsIcCharInd -1)

Comment: That will work fine. `i` will be equal to -1 and therefore `_current` will be set to -1. You could also remove the `If` statement that I added, and `_current` will always be set to the value of `i` or zero, if you don't pass it as a parameter.

Comment: If i do i Optional, i will give a constant value for it, but i need  it like a indexator

As indexator I mean, that i can wright like this: 

WsItemGrp.WsItemIcChar(WsIcCharInd -1)

the first variant gives this error:

Properties with no required parameters cannot be declared 'Default'.